# theres two images with different classes, and I have two paragraphs within one article class. How do I place eah image above each individual paragraph

Tags: html, css, image, mobile-website

I'm building a responsive website, and I have an issue with placement of images on a ***mobile screen***.

There's two images in html

```
<img class="img-2yb" src="img/2yb5z6lqp4v71.jpg" alt="img beside ig">
<img class="astro-img" src="img/satecastro.jpg" alt ="satec astro image">
```

Alongside that, there's these two paragraphs. They're both within the `<article></arcticle>` tag, with the class "img-info".
The two paragraphs are formatted like this:

```
<h3> title #1 </h3> 
<p style = "color:#89a227"   > <i> green color text</i> 
<p> big paragraph words blah blah </p>

<h3> title #2 </h3> 
<p style = "color:#89a227"   > <i> green color text #2</i> 
<p> big paragraph words blah blah #2 </p>
```

The entire section (imgs and the paragraphs) are within a div tag class  = 'wrapper'. The entire section looks something like this:

```css
* {
  /* default is phone screen styling */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  color: #50555c;
}

.img-banner {
  width: 100%
}

.img-info {
  /* article tag */
  width: 100%;
}

.img-info h3 {
  /* title for job */
  padding: 20px 30px 10px;
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.img-info h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.img-info p {
  padding: 0px 30px 20px;
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #50555c;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.img-2yb {
  /* 1st img beside text */
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}


/*satec astro div tags begin */

.astro-img {
  /* 1st img beside text */
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}


/*
    the css code that controls the images is:
*/

.img-2yb {
  /* 1st img beside text */
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}


/*satec astro div tags begin */

.astro-img {
  /* 1st img beside text */
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- div class for the first expreience -->
  <article class="img-info">
    <h2> Big title at the top of site</h2>
    <!-- literally the title :D -->
    <h3><strong> title 1 </strong></h3>
    <p style="color:#89a227"> <i> green text #1</i>
    </p>
    <!-- green color -->
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus ipsum diam, et viverra justo pretium et.
      <br><br> Mauris laoreet ut leo at ornare. In gravida porta tellus non volutpat. Integer tristique, erat sit amet venenatis porttitor, turpis nunc venenatis leo, vitae tincidunt velit ex non turpis. Sed suscipit mauris vel bibendum auctor. Nunc commodo
      elementum urna vel luctus. Curabitur tincidunt dolor vel viverra hendrerit.
      <br><br> Vivamus malesuada purus nec enim tempus, nec tincidunt lorem lobortis. Praesent congue dolor nisl, quis pharetra nisl facilisis a. Aenean pretium, nulla et cursus tristique, ex velit vehicula magna, in tempus tortor nunc quis est. Aenean
      sagittis augue eget elit ornare, id suscipit est ultrices.
      <br><br> Sed ligula nisl, ullamcorper vitae mi id, egestas blandit dolor. Nam ac feugiat dolor, a dictum turpis. Cras sed urna eu augue tristique aliquet viverra ut magna. Phasellus dapibus lectus ut felis ultrices egestas. In consequat, ipsum id
      luctus scelerisque, magna lectus tincidunt dolor, in dapibus nulla mauris in massa. Nulla rutrum, quam et hendrerit pulvinar, nibh.
      <br><br>
      <br>
    </p>

    <h3><b>title 2</b></h3>
    <p style="color:#89a227"><i>    green text #2 </i></p>
    <p> sentence<br><br> sentence. <br><br> sentence
    </p>

  </article>
  <img class="img-2yb" src="img/2yb5z6lqp4v71.jpg" alt="img beside ig">
  <img class="astro-img" src="img/satecastro.jpg" alt="astro image">
</div>
```

As you may deduce, the freakishly small images reside at the bottom of the screen on the left and right (float). I want it so that img 1 is on top of the first `<h3> </h3>` words, and img 2 is on top of the 2nd `<h3></h3>` words.

Comment: "*I want it so that img 1 is on top of the first...*" - so why did you add the `<img>` elements so far aware from the elements to which you want them to be adjacent?

Comment: @DavidThomas ig neatness lol. I wanted all the img tags in one area so if I need to mess with the images, I can do so without scouring through the code. Plus it doesn't rlly affect the actual location of the image, so why not?

Comment: I'd argue that this is an approach that works counter to your requirements. If you wrap the various elements consistently, and each area contains its own contents then styling becomes far easier and it's obvious where all the elements will be. Where the elements are in the HTML directly affects the ease of maintenance and association of those elements with the their related content. But, while I disagree with your position, this is your project and you are - of course - correct to work in the way you wish to work (though I feel it will cause your problems).

Comment: Incidentally, as an example of how "easy" it can be, with properly structured (imho, ymmv, etc) HTML, this - relatively simple and responsive demo - works perfectly well on desktop, phone and tablet: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/20Loh7ms/show

Answer (score 0):

First, NEVER use float unless you have to.  It takes the element out of the flow of the doc and makes it harder to build scalable responsive designs.

Second, read up on flex.  Within <article> you basically have 4 sections.  2 paragraphs and 2 images.  Make article{display:flex;} and add class box. wrap each section in a div

Third, for the box class use the order property.  If you label the order 1,2,3,4 the pictures will appear on the bottom.

```css
* {
  /* default is phone screen styling */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

p {
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  color: #50555c;
}

.img-banner {
  width: 100%
}

.img-info {
  /* article tag */
  width: 100%;
}

.img-info h3 {
  /* title for job */
  padding: 20px 30px 10px;
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.img-info h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.img-info p {
  padding: 0px 30px 20px;
  font-family: 'charukola-unicode-regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #50555c;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.img-2yb {
  /* 1st img beside text */
  width: 25%;
}


/*satec astro div tags begin */

.astro-img {
  /* 1st img beside text */
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 20%;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .box :nth-child(1) { order: 2;align-self:start }
  .box :nth-child(2) { order: 4; }
  .box :nth-child(3) { order: 1; }
  .box :nth-child(4) { order: 3; align-self:end;}
  
  .astro-img{
  width:10vw;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- div class for the first expreience -->
  <article class="img-info box">
    <div>
      <h2> Big title at the top of site</h2>
      <!-- literally the title :D -->
      <h3><strong> title 1 </strong></h3>
      <p style="color:#89a227"> <i> green text #1</i>
      </p>
      <!-- green color -->
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus ipsum diam, et viverra justo pretium et.
        <br><br> Mauris laoreet ut leo at ornare. In gravida porta tellus non volutpat. Integer tristique, erat sit amet venenatis porttitor, turpis nunc venenatis leo, vitae tincidunt velit ex non turpis. Sed suscipit mauris vel bibendum auctor. Nunc
        commodo elementum urna vel luctus. Curabitur tincidunt dolor vel viverra hendrerit.
        <br><br> Vivamus malesuada purus nec enim tempus, nec tincidunt lorem lobortis. Praesent congue dolor nisl, quis pharetra nisl facilisis a. Aenean pretium, nulla et cursus tristique, ex velit vehicula magna, in tempus tortor nunc quis est. Aenean
        sagittis augue eget elit ornare, id suscipit est ultrices.
        <br><br> Sed ligula nisl, ullamcorper vitae mi id, egestas blandit dolor. Nam ac feugiat dolor, a dictum turpis. Cras sed urna eu augue tristique aliquet viverra ut magna. Phasellus dapibus lectus ut felis ultrices egestas. In consequat, ipsum
        id luctus scelerisque, magna lectus tincidunt dolor, in dapibus nulla mauris in massa. Nulla rutrum, quam et hendrerit pulvinar, nibh.
        <br><br>
        <br>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class='box'>
      <h3><b>title 2</b></h3>
      <p style="color:#89a227"><i>  green text #2 </i></p>
      <p> sentence<br><br> sentence. <br><br> sentence
      </p>

    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="img-2yb" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="img beside ig">
    </div>
    <div>
    <img class="astro-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="astro image">
    </div>
  </article>


</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response! So i implemented your css & html code provided, and it does seem better than mine. I am running into a few issues tho.


First and most importantly, it fucks up my ipad and normal pc screen view. I had those two views down to a pixel, but the new code rlly messes them up.

Secondly, these are nitpicks that im sure I can solve, so sorry for sounding like an ass, but would appreciate some help with! The image that's supposed to be ontop of the 1st paragraph is on top of the big bold <h1> header. The images arrer sorta to the left and right (but im sure i can fix).

Comment: mainly tho, I'm worried about it messing up the views for ipad and laptop screens. I think the issue is that you can't really see the entire project. 
Would it be okay with you if I share with you my github repo which holds the files? It has everything i've done so far. If you could spare a struggling and daft young programmer a few minutes of your day, and leave me some constructive feedback for my code, or help edit it a bit, i'd really really appreciate it! :)

Comment: you will need to look into media queries.  Different size screens require different css.  If you want more help, accept the answer as it answers the question you asked and then ask a new question.